# can't sent email to gmail account with smtp and PHP mailer

Tags: email, smtp, gmail, phpmailer

i have PHP mailer. when i run it to send an email to yahoo account it works fine. but when i send to gmail account it havent been sent. even the email_debugger says that it have been sent succesfuly. anyone can help me?

this is my mail config

```
$this->load->library('email');
$config['useragent']        = 'PHPMailer';              // Mail engine switcher:   'CodeIgniter' or 'PHPMailer'
$config['protocol']         = 'smtp';                   // 'mail', 'sendmail', or 'smtp'
$config['mailpath']         = 'PHPMailer';
$config['smtp_host']        = 'domain.com';
$config['smtp_user']        = 'example@domain.com';
$config['smtp_pass']        = 'example';
$config['smtp_port']        = 25;
$config['smtp_timeout']     = 65;                        // (in seconds)
$config['smtp_crypto']      = 'ssl';                    // '' or 'tls' or 'ssl'
$config['smtp_debug']       = 3;                        // PHPMailer's SMTP debug info  level: 0 = off, 1 = commands, 2 = commands and data, 3 = as 2 plus connection status, 4 = low level data output.
$config['wordwrap']         = true;
$config['wrapchars']        = 76;
$config['mailtype']         = 'html';                   // 'text' or 'html'
$config['charset']          = 'utf-8';
$config['validate']         = true;
$config['priority']         = 3;                        // 1, 2, 3, 4, 5
$config['crlf']             = "r\n";                     // "\r\n" or "\n" or "\r"
$config['newline']          = "r\n";                     // "\r\n" or "\n" or "\r"
$config['bcc_batch_mode']   = false;
$config['bcc_batch_size']   = 200;
$config['mailtype'] = 'html';
$this->email->initialize($config);

$subject       = 'Design Consulting oleh '.$nama;
$this->email->from($email, $nama);

$this->email->to($to);

$this->email->subject($subject);

$this->email->message($mail_body);  

if ($this->email->send())
        {
            $this->session->set_flashdata('message', '<div class="success">Thank you, your message successfully sent to our email Management.</div>');
         //echo $this->email->print_debugger(); 
            redirect($this->web_url.'/consulting/');

        }
        else
        {
            $this->session->set_flashdata('message', '<div class="error">Something went wrong, please try again or contact the helpdesk.</div>');
            redirect($this->web_url.'/consulting/');

        }
```

any one can help me? thanks.

Comment: Have you checked spam folders on gmail account? What mail provider do you use for sending you mail? It could be that the gmail MTA doesn't accept the incoming emails from your provider (you could check this by sending an email directly from you're used mail provider).

Comment: thankyou for ur reply ._.

i have checked it and there is nothing there  . btw how to check it. wheter the gmail MTA accept or not. i dont get it :| .

Comment: My idea was sending an email from the email account you're using with phpmailer (I guessed "domain.com" isn't the smtp host you're actually using) via webmail, direct smtp access or whatever options you have with this mail provider to check if this is a problem of your mail provider or a problem with phpmailer.